# How to know which exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception

I'm doing a review for our codebase, and there are many statements like this:

```
try
{
   doSomething()
} catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

but I would like a way to know which exception is thrown by doSomething() (there's no throw statement in the implementation of doSomething) so i can catch that exception instead of just catching Exception in general, even with findBugs it gives a warning `REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION`.

I should mention that logging the exception or printing it to console will not help me because it takes time in this case to reproduce the error that causes the exception here.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If there's no `throws` statement in `doSomething` (e.g. `doSomething() throws IOException`), any exceptions that will occur will be an instance of `RuntimeException`. If you want to know the exact class of an exception thrown by `doSomething`, you can always try

```
try {
   doSomething();
} catch (RuntimeException e){
   System.out.println(e.getClass().getName());
}
```

Knowing which runtime exceptions can be thrown without actually running the program is difficult. Even if none of the code that `doSomething()` calls has an explicit throw, core java operations can always throw `NullPointerException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, etc with the wrong input. Here are some ideas:

- Dig through manually. At least you will know some of the exceptions.
- Use reflection to find any throw statements accessible from `doSomething`.
- Run your test cases and log the exceptions thrown like above. Good tests will reveal the important errors that callers of `doSomething` should be ready for.
- Go to the people who put the catch there in the first place

In any case it's usually a good idea to catch exceptions that are as specific as possible, since you don't know exactly *what* went wrong when you try to deal with all cases in one clause.

Comment: If you add an exception that will never be thrown, Eclipse gives an error - "Unreachable catch block for MyException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body". How does Eclipse know this?

Comment: The java compiler (not really ecplise itself) knows which checked exceptions (i.e. not the `RuntimeException` explained in my answer) are thrown by looking at `throws` statements of called methods. If a checked exception is declared in a `catch` block without it being thrown, you will get this error. PS: this is a comment on a pretty old question, and not directly related to the original question. You probably want to ask a new question next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can 1) dig through all the code in doSomething() and everything it calls to see the exception handling and what RuntimeExceptions can be thrown, or 2) take of the `catch (Exception e)` and wait for it to fail. This is the problem that checked exceptions attempted to overcome by making a strongly-typed declaration in method signatures about what exceptions must be handled as a result of calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `throws` clause, then the method does not throw any *checked* execption. The javadoc of that method might give information about any *unchecked* exceptions the method can throw, but it does not have to.

Why do you want to catch any exceptions in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to catch just compile-time exceptions or run-time exceptions as well? If you only want to catch the compile-time ones, just remove your current catch block - you'll immediately get error messages stating that certain exceptions aren't being caught. After you add one exception, you'll see error messages for others - you'll be able to finish catching all possible exceptions thrown by your code block.