# Should i catch all the exception which are thrown by a method?

Tags: java, exception

```
try{
   output.format("%d %s %s %.2f%n", input.nextInt(),
        input.next(),input.next(),input.nextDouble());
} catch(FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException){
    System.err.println("Error writing to file. Terminating.");
    break;
} catch(NoSuchElementException noSuchElementException){
    System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
    input.nextLine();
}
```

The method `format(String format, Object... args)` in `Formatter` class throws two `exception`: `IllegalFormatException` and `FormatterClosedException` but in my book the above code catches `NoSuchElementException` and `FormatterClosedException`.

1. Why did the code catch `NoSuchElementException` but did not catch `IllegalFormatException`?
2. How can we know if we need to catch `NoSuchElementException` if it is not even stated in the Formatter class format() method in the online [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) ?

Comment: try reading topic on Exceptions e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586305/how-to-know-which-exception-is-thrown

Comment: [Read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) you will understand NoSuchElementException

Comment: I gave you the explanation at the end of the answer. It's the `Scanner` who can throw `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: The `NoSuchElementException` has nothing to do with `Formatter.format`. It can be thrown by the `Scanner` methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html): `java.util.NoSuchElementException` is a **`RuntimeException`** which can be
>   thrown by different classes in Java like Iterator, Enumerator, **Scanner**
>   or StringTokenizer.

In your case it is `Scanner`. Its not from `format` method.

**It's** just to be in the safer side(if next input is not given then throw this exception).

Sample code which shows the demo

```
public class NoSuchElementExceptionDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hashtable sampleMap = new Hashtable();
        Enumeration enumeration = sampleMap.elements();
        enumeration.nextElement();  //java.util.NoSuchElementExcepiton here because enumeration is empty
    }
}

Output:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Hashtable Enumerator
        at java.util.Hashtable$EmptyEnumerator.nextElement(Hashtable.java:1084)
        at test.ExceptionTest.main(NoSuchElementExceptionDemo.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java Exceptions are used for marking unexpected situations. For example parsing non-numeric `String` to a number (`NumberFormatException`) or calling a method on a `null` reference (`NullPointerException`). You can catch them in many ways.

```
try{
    //some code
} catch (FormatterClosedException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace()     //very important - handles the Exception but prints the information!
} catch (NoSuchElementException e2) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or using the fact, that they all extend `Exception`:

```
try {
    //somecode
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
};
```

or since Java 7:

```
try {
    //somecode
} catch (FormatterClosedException | NoSuchElementExceptione) {
    e.printStackTrace;
};
```

You have to catch all `checked exceptions`. It's due to the language grammar. On the other hand, there are `unchecked exceptions` which doesn't necessarily need to be caught.

`IllegalArgumentException` is unchecked exception and therefor doesn't need to be caught.
`NoSuchInputException` can be thrown by `input.next()`. That's why it's declared to be caught.

So:

1. you're dealing with 3 different `Exception`s.
2. They all are unchecked so don't have to be caught.
3. `input.next()` can `throw NoSuchElementException`
4. `format` can `throw FormatterClosedException`

Comment: I guess because you didnt answer the question. Maybe you missread and went in the wrong direction. He just asked why he has to catch the exceptions seen in his post, (Why the book tells him to catch these) and where they come from.

Comment: Read the last part of the answer

Comment: well I didn't downvote :) Just guessed without reading your text very carefully.

Answer (score -1):

add another `catch` with `Exception` class. That is the parent class.

```
catch(Exception e){
//your message or
     System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

You can add `catch` for every `exception` that your code throws and in the end add this catch with this Exception parent class. If your `exception` is not caught by any of the `catch` then this will caught your exception.

It will catch all exceptions that is raised by your program.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to switch from specific exceptions to the generic exception. Informations can get lost and specific exceptions will help debugging. (didn't downvote though)

Comment: yeah. i know, but in the end you should use this, if you don't know what exception can be throw by the program.